# What could be a good benchmarking method to compare MPI and MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mpi, cluster-computing, benchmarking

I know the rule of thumb of it:
    Big data, non-iterative, fault tolerant => MapReduce ; 
    Speed, small data, iterative, non-Mapper-Reducer type => MPI ([Hadoop MapReduce vs MPI (vs Spark vs Mahout vs Mesos) - When to use one over the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791531/hadoop-mapreduce-vs-mpi-vs-spark-vs-mahout-vs-mesos-when-to-use-one-over-the)).

What i want to know is what benchmarking method should i use to prove MapReduce is good for Big data, non-iterative, fault tolerant case. And what benchmarking method should i use to prove MPI is excel in Speed, small data, and iterative case.

Really appreciate any help you can provide

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [BigDataBench](http://prof.ict.ac.cn/BigDataBench/). It has a range of different workloads and it also works with MPI. Maybe checking out their existing publications could be helpful as well.